# Disabling "org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank" on jsp

Tags: javascript, spring

We are calling hibernate validation in Spring framework. We want to know how to disable 
"org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank" validation on the .jsp page on radio button selection. On no radio button selection this validation should work.